# Merging CSV files with different BUT similar column headers

Tags: sql, csv

I have about 5000 CSV files and they all have different but similar columns. Like the following two table abstracts:

```
Table1:

First Name,Last Name,email

Table2:

first_name,last_name,e-mail
```

I tried using the Levenshtein Distance to map all columns from tables to master list headers. It works all right but it is not very accurate and sometimes I lose data if there is no good match. Is there a tool that does something like this? Or is this tool I've written is possibly the best shot I have to accomplish this.

Comment: If the tables you've supplied have columns in the above order, you should just merge them by their order. AFAIK, this is not possible with all RDBM's. Do alter'ing column names possible in your situation?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The ordering can be random and some tables might have extra columns which I currently just ignore.

Comment: I think you ***may*** have to group all common names for a given column and create a list for that. I understand that it will take time. But it is more precise then fuzzy matching. The advantage is in that, that if some column misses the matching, then you can see that somewhere in the log and update the list of the column names properly. At some point of a time, I think, misses would be rare.